# To check if the given function is differentiable twice or not?

Tags: calculus

$ f(x) = \frac{ \sin x}{x}$ if $x ≠ 0$

$= 1, x = 0$

I checked its differentiability, and it is differentiable once.

To check if it is differentiable more than once I differentiated the function again and got

$ f(x) = \frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{x^2} , x ≠ 0$

$ = 0, x = 0$

And checked its differentiability, again it's differentiable.

Is this right method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case for,

$f(x) = {\frac {sin(x)}{x}}$ and $f(0) = 1$

We see that the limit of the function as $x$ approaches 0 is in fact 1, So the function is continuous and differentiable at even $x=0$.
Graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xd65iy7qqm

Now $f'(x) = \frac {cos(x)}{x} - \frac {sinx}{x^2}$ and $f'(0) = 0$

We see that the limit of this function at $x=0$ is $0$. So the function is continuous. Graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kz0soz5seg.

And hence, the function is differentiable.

Edit: I had got the graph wrong in my previous edit and hence came up with a wrong answer. But I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f$ is the so-called *sinc function*. This function is infinitely differentiable on all of ${\mathbb R}$, even of ${\mathbb C}$. This can be seen in various ways:

- One has
  $${\rm sinc}(x)=1-{x^2\over3!}+{x^4\over5!}-{x^6\over 7!}+\ldots\ \ .$$
  The right hand side is a power series with convergence radius $\rho=\infty$. Therefore the function defined by this series can be differentiated termwise as often as you like.
- You can write
  $${\rm sinc}(x)=\int_0^1\cos(t\,x)\>dt\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})$$
  (check this!). On the right hand side the $x$ is a "parameter" in the integral. One may differentiate the integral with respect to $x$ by partially differentiating the integrand with respect to $x$, 
  $${\rm sinc}'(x)=\int_0^1-t\sin(t\,x)\>dt\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
  and so on.